# Smart Cards in Java Kerberos

Tags: java, kerberos, smartcard

**Prerequisites**:

- I set up a basic `Kerberos` realm via `Windows Active Directory`.
- I managed to successfully login into service via *login/password* pair using `Java Kerberos` (`Krb5LoginModule`), which is provided via `JAAS`.

Now I try to implement Kerberos login via smart card. 
Smart card preauthentication in Kerberos is done via `AS-REQ/AS-REP` messages (`PA-PK-AS-REQ/P` extensions). Unfortunately, JAAS Kerberos hasn't used the smartcard.

**Question**: Does Java Kerberos support smart card preauthentication out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support (yet). You should raise this on the security-dev mailing list of the OpenJDK project.